# Desktop's "Connect to Server" function repeatedly asks for SSH password after connecting

Tags: 12.04, server, nautilus, ssh, password

I would like to use the "Connect to Server" function (available from the Ubuntu desktop menu) to open a Nautilus window showing the file system of another machine through SSH, since I find it easier for simple file copying (and similar) tasks.

Previously, I was able to do that just fine, entering the **Server**'s IP address, **Type:** SSH and **User name** fields for the remote machine into the **Connect to Server** dialog box that pops up when clicking this menu entry and entering the remote machine's password on request.

Recently however, after clicking the **Connect** button, a modal input window kept asking me for the password repeatedly. The first 10 or so times I actually entered the correct password for the remote machine, after that I just left it blank but it kept re-opening each time I pressed either one of the **Ok**, **Cancel** or **X** (window close) buttons or the Enter key. After many times, a Nautilus window actually opened, but it kept asking me for the password. After even more times, the dialog didn't come up by itself, so I thought I could now browse the remote machine's file system.

Unfortunately even then, as soon as I clicked a folder or file, I had to click away many of the password requests again.

Interestingly, I was able to browse or even copy files between machines, even though I didn't enter any password on those useless prompts.
b
I also tried the whole process again (after restarting both machines), this time with the **Password** and **Remember this password** options set in the **Connect to Server** dialog. Didn't make any difference.

This password prompt is especially annoying because it is system-modal, which means I can't do anything else (not even switch to another window) if it is visible.

Any idea what might be causing this? Or should I switch to a different remote mouting GUI such as Gigolo?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: I have successfully used the ssh credentials by entering: ssh://username@hostname in the "connect to host" field. It will connect using ssh encryption keys instead of password. Not a password, but it does work well.